# Node.js w/ Bookshelf; set values for a many-to-many relation with an array of IDs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm using Node.js with Bookshelf to setup an API. The JSON coming in the request looks like this

```
{
  conversation:  {
    user_ids: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }
}
```

The conversation object looks like this:

```
var Conversation = storeManager.bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'conversations',

  users: function() {
    this.belongsToMany(User)
  }

})
```

The user looks like this:

```
var User = storeManager.bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',

  conversations: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Conversation)
  }
})
```

The database has a conversations and users table along with a conversations_users table that has a `user_id` and `conversation_id` field.

So I've been going through the docs and I'm struggling to figure out how I can create a conversation object that has a relationship with the existing users with the given IDs.

Here is what I have in my controller so far

```
ConversationController.prototype.create = function(req, res, next) {
  // Create the conversation
  Conversation.forge().set('users', req.body['conversation']['user_ids']).save().then(function(model) {
    req.conversation = model
    next()
  }).catch(function(err) {
    res.status(400).send(err)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the add method on your collection like so:

```
Conversations_Users.add({userId:1,conversation_id:1});
```

then call

```
Conversations_Users.save()
```

Comment: Okay. I didn't want to have to make these records individually. I was hoping there was a easy way I could add them to the record before saving. With Active Model this is possible. It doesn't create records in the join table unless the first record saves. Then if one of the records you are trying to join doesn't exist it bails and deletes all previously saved records. Gives you a little transaction control so you don't have incomplete records hanging around. Oh well, guess I'll have to roll that myself.

Comment: Is the collection Conversations_Users automatically created? Is it necessarily a collection or could it be a model?